# Example, Field of rational functions and a special automorphism group

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, galois-theory

I am refering to an example from the famous book *Galois Thery* by Emil Artin. There on page 38 he gave the following example as an application of the Theorem.

> (Theorem 13) If $\sigma_1, \ldots, \sigma_n$ are $n$ mutually distinct isomorphisms of a field E into a field E', and if F is the fixed field of E, then $(E/F) \ge n$.

The example.

> Let $k$ be a field and consider the field $E = k(x)$ of all rational functions of the variable $x$. If we map each of the functions $f(x)$ of $E$ onto $f(\frac{1}{x})$ we obviously obtain an automorphism of $E$. Let us consider the following six automorphism where $f(x)$ is mapped onto $f(x) (identity), f(1-x), f(\frac{1}{x}), f(1-\frac{1}{x}), f(\frac{1}{1-x})$ and $f(\frac{x}{x-1})$ and call $F$ the fixed point field. F consists of all rational functions satisfying
>   $$
>  (1) \quad f(x) = f(1-x) = f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) = f\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right) = f\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right) = f\left(\frac{x}{x-1}\right).
> $$
>   It suffices to check the first two equalities, the others being consequences. The function
>   $$
>  (2) \quad I = I(x) = \frac{(x^2 - x + 1)^3}{x^2(x-1)^2}
> $$
>   belongs to F as is readily seen. Hence, the field S = k(I) of all rational functions of I will belong to F.
>
> We contend: F = S and (E/F) = 6.
>   Indeed, from Theorem 13 we obtain $(E/F) \ge 6$. Since $S \subseteq F$ if suffices to prove (E/S) = 6. Now E = S(x). It is thus sufficient to find some 6-th degree equation with coefficients in S satisfied by x. The following one is obviously satisfied;
>   $$
>  (x^2 - x + 1)^3 - 1\cdot x^2(x-1)^2 = 0.
> $$
>   The reader will find the study of these fields a profitable exercise. At a later occasion he will be able to derive all intermediate fields.

The last paragraph I cannot follow, (1) why $E = S(x)$ and (2) why does the polynomial
$$
 (x^2 - x + 1)^3 - 1\cdot x^2(x-1)^2 = 0.
$$
is obviously satisfied by $x$, I am confused because polynomials in $x$ are coefficients and the variable $x$ also occurs as a variable of the polynomial with coefficient which also contain $x$, shouldn't they be distinguished as two separate variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a misprint in
$$
 (x^2 - x + 1)^3 - 1\cdot x^2(x-1)^2 = 0,
$$
it should read
$$
 (x^2 - x + 1)^3 - I \cdot x^2(x-1)^2 = 0,
$$
which is indeed obvious, given the definition of $I$.

As to why $E = S(x)$, just note that $E = k(x)$, and $S = k(I) \supseteq k$, with $I \in E$.